# Make axis2 deliver non XML messages to service

Tags: apache-axis

Is it possible to make Axis2 accept non XML messages? I know it can take Rest messages, but I have a requirement to accommodate some older products which won't send a well formed XML message to the services.
We are currently using synapse, it acts as proxy in between client and services but we are trying to get away from synapse.

In short I want Axis2 to deliver message to a service whether or not it's Valid according to Axis2